# Multidex application crashing even though class does exist

Tags: android, dex, android-multidex

My android multidex application sometimes crashes on older versions of Android, in this case specially android 21 and on a nexus 7 2013.

The issue is that on startup there are occasional crashes of a classdef not found on the dex path. However I have opened the first `.apk` that android looks at in that path given and after going through the 100+ `.dex` files, indeed found my so called missing class.

I'm wondering, does android start running an application perhaps before all the dex files have been loaded? How can I fix this? Make sure that my dex file is loaded before any class is used.

Comment: See [multidex](https://medium.com/groupon-eng/android-s-multidex-slows-down-app-startup-d9f10b46770f) "While setting up multidexing for your project, you may notice a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running your app. This means that the class for app startup is not located in the main dex file. The Android plugin for Gradle in Android SDK Build Tools 21.1 or higher has multidex support."

Comment: @JonGoodwin Interesting, thank you, that's something to play with.